# Skitter-Jquery Sideshow- want to reduce the square size

Tags: javascript, jquery, skitter-slider

I found this  jQuery slideshow called Skitter. it's awesome! so I implemented it in my latest project.
 I am using square effect..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box_skitter_small').skitter({show_randomly: true, dots: true, interval:1000, numbers_align: 'center', theme: 'square'});
    });
```

I could not find the function.Please help me

Answer (score 0):

modify Square theme css width and height in skitter.styles.css inside css folder

it has some default setting for every theme
look the first default lines

```
/* =Square theme
-------------------------------------------------------------- */

.skitter-square .play_pause_button, 
.skitter-square .next_button, 
.skitter-square .focus_button, 
.skitter-square .prev_button 
{
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/sprite-square.png') no-repeat;
}

.skitter-square .play_pause_button {
    background-position: -55px -0px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    top: 10px !important;
    left: 10px !important;
    bottom: auto !important;
    right: auto !important;
    margin-top:0;
}

.skitter-square .play_pause_button.play_button {
    background-position: -0px -0px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
}
```